# Inserting node at rear end in a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am coding on inserting a node at the end in a singly LinkedList. Program is executing without any errors but running an infinite loop after entering the very first number. I can't find the logical error I have committed in the code. Any help would be appreciable :).

Here is the code and what I've tried:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node* head = NULL; // empty list
node* temp;
void insert(int x){
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) head = temp; 
    node* temp1 = head;
    // traversing the list
    while(temp1 -> next != NULL){
    temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }   
    temp1 -> next = temp;
}
void print(){
    node* iterator = head;
    while(iterator != NULL){
        cout << iterator -> data;
        iterator = iterator -> next;
    }
}
int main(){
    int n, x;
    cout << "how many numbers\n";
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "enter the value";
        cin >> x;
        insert(x);
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be a linked list but the o/p is an infinite number of first entered number/data ('x' in this case)

Comment: Use `new` to allocate new nodes, and properly initialize the member variables using a constructor function. Especially `next` must be initialized with `NULL` (or even better with `nullptr`).

Comment: It's funny `Program is executing without any errors` but `running an infinite loop after entering the very first number.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ tried it using your way, still an infinite loop. Would you mind executing the code on your machine?

Comment: @HikkiGOAT Would you mind to inspect your code with the debugger please?

Comment: @john I mean the logical error. Lol, my bad. A common beginner mistake

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry bro, but I don't have any idea how to debug code :(

Comment: @HikkiGOAT That's an essential skill that every programmer should get familiar with from hour zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh! So I must go see some online tutorials on debugging. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the logic of the `insert` function is clearly wrong

Lets step though it.

First you allocate the node and assign it to `temp`. Since this is C++ you should use new and you should use a constructor, but we'll let that pass.

Then since `head` equals NULL you set `head` to the `temp`.

Then you set `temp1` to `head`, which because of the previous step means `temp1` equals `temp`.

Then you loop to the last node pointed to by `temp1`. In this case you're already at the last node so the loop isn't entered.

Then you set `temp1->next` to `temp`, but remember that `temp1` equals `temp`, (see two steps previous), so now you've created a circular list. This explains your infinite loop.

I'm guessing that you meant to write this

```
if (head == NULL) { head = temp; return; }
```

or maybe this

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = temp; 
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, bro. I meant to write the second snippet. What does the "return;" in the first snippet means? And why should I use the constructor? And thanks a lot for clarifying the problem :)

Comment: `return` would exit the function immediately at that point. So the difference between that and what you intended is just a matter of style.

Comment: It's actually more important to be using `new` instead of `malloc`. The principal difference between `new` and `malloc` is that `new` will call the constructor for the object being created (if it exists) but `malloc` will not. So using `malloc` you can end up with unconstructed objects which is often bad news, although it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: As for why you should use constructors, it's just that how objects are initialised is very important, and in object oriented programming you want to control that process, and in C++ constructors are the way you do that. The need for them will become clearer as you get more experience, but there's no harm in getting into good habits now.

Comment: @john I knew that c++ uses "new" now and whenever we will be creating a new node new will call the constructor and the constructor then will initialize the data field. I was thinking there would be another reason for using constructors other than this. Actually, the tutorial i was following uses  malloc for providing the indepth knowledge on how a memory block is allocated dynamically. And yes  thanks for clarifying this as well :).